# Is it possible to reflect over a hosting assembly?

Tags: c#

For example, IIS hosts ASP assemblies, and SQL Server hosts SqlClr assemblies. If I were to write a hosting server application, would it be possible for hosted assemblies to reflect over the hosting application? Or do app-domains protect against that?

For the record, I'm not trying to reflect over other people's assemblies, I'm more interested in protecting against having other people reflect over mine.

Comment: Yes, a web server or SQL server runs in a room with a solid lock on the door.  That keeps "other people", as well as their code, away from yours.  Software security has never ever been a substitute for physical security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the hosted assembly has the Reflection permission (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.reflectionpermission.aspx), it can reflect over any types it gets a hold of. So if you are concerned about somebody "snooping" your code, make sure the hosted assemblies run sandboxed without that permission.

Note: Microsoft keeps changing the exact restrictions that apply with every other service pack. It is save to assume that everything that is declared as "public" will allow the code to use it in reflection, regardless of permissions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.reflectionpermissionflag.aspx  But since the hosted code has to interact with your hosting application through these public APIs, hiding them from reflection wouldn't serve any true benefit in either way.

Comment: Hmm. What do you think about a sort of layer cake solution where the bottom is the 'private' assembly, the middle is the generic public information assembly, and the top is the user assembly?

Comment: Such a layer solution should prevent a restricted assembly from peeking into anything in the "private" assembly. Personally I design plugin (i.e. hosting) based application around a common "Something.Interfaces.dll" which is all public and the real exe is all internal.

Comment: Cool, much appreciate the answer.